# String.charAt() returning weird result in java

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, char, indexof

i have the following code

```
String[] alphabet = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
                "o", "p", "q","r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
```

if i do

```
 String str = "aa";
 for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
    chars.add(Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(str.charAt(i)));
 }
```

the values in chars are

```
0 = -1
1 = -1
```

as the result returned by  Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(str.charAt(i)) is 'a'97   and not "a"
hence its not matching due to which -1 is being returned

I need `Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(str.charAt(i))`  to return "a" 
that's what i thought `charAt` returns which is just "a" and not this  'a' 97

any alternative ?

Comment: If it's returning -1 that means the `List` doesn't contain what you're searching for. You're searching a `String` list for a `char`

Comment: sure that `Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(str.charAt(i))` is returning 'a'? it looks more like `-1`

Comment: ohh, and `char` is an integer type (kind of) and you can do maths with it : `str.charAt(i) - 'a'` will return zero for `a`, 1 for `b`, ... no need for array/list in above code - or e.g. `'b' - 'a' == 1`

Answer (score 6):

`str.charAt(i)` returns a `char`  and the `List` contains `String` elements.
As a `char` is not a `String` and `String.equals()` and `Character.equals()` are not interoperable between them (`"a".equals('a')` and `Character.valueOf('a').equals("a")` return `false`), `stringList.indexOf(anyChar)` will always return `-1`.

You could replace :

```
chars.add(Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(str.charAt(i)));
                ^----- List<String>          ^----- char (that will be boxed to Character)
```

by :

```
chars.add(Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i))));
                ^----- List<String>             ^----- String
```

to compare `String` with `String`.

Or as alternative compare `char` with `char` by relying on `char[]` instead of `String[]` such as :

```
char[] alphabet = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
        'o', 'p', 'q','r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
```

In this way this will compile fine :

```
List<Character> charList = IntStream.range(0, alphabet.length)
                                          .mapToObj(i -> alphabet[i])
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
chars.add(charList.indexOf(str.charAt(i))); 
            ^------- List<Character>      ^------ char (that will be boxed to Character)
```

---

Not your direct question but creating the same `List` at each iteration is not logical and is a little some waste.
Instantiating it once before the loop is more efficient :

```
List<String> alphabetList = Arrays.asList(alphabet);
String str = "aa";
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
   chars.add(alphabetList.indexOf(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i))));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that chars and Strings are not the same thing in Java. A `char` is a primitive, numerical type, and its literals are given using single quotes (e.g. `'a'`). A String is a reference type that logically consists of multiple characters.

The simplest solution would be to make your alphabet a single string:

```
String alphabet = "abcdef...";
```

and to scan that string when finding the index:

```
 chars.add(alphabet.indexOf(str.charAt(i)));
```

Note that this now uses [`String.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) and not the `List` indexOf method that you were using before.

Alternatively, convert `alphabet` to be an array of characters:

```
char[] alphabet = new char[] {'a', 'b', /* ... */ };
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList(alphabet)` is a `List<String>`. It does not contain anything of type `Character`.

If you want to look for a String consisting of that single character, build a string of that single character:

```
Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)))
```

or

```
Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(str.substring(i, i+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `char != string` in java,

So to resolve your problem,

```
Arrays.<String>asList(alphabet).indexOf(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)))
```

Now you will get your output as expected.

So the problem was that you created List of String and was looking for a character in string so java was unable to find it. So it returned `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the String to a character array and iterate through that:

```
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();

    String str = "abc";

    for ( Character character : str.toCharArray() )
    {
        indices.add(Arrays.asList(alphabet).indexOf(character.toString()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do integer operations on `char` - it is an integral type (displayed as character). Examples: `'b' - 'a' == 1`, `'c' - 'a' == 2`, and so on. (Actually `'a' == 97` , its Unicode value).

For the given code, there is no need for the array or a list, it could be written as

```
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    chars.add(str.charAt(i) - 'a');
}
```

sure the loop can be written as

```
for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    chars.add(ch - 'a');
}
```

or even using streams:

```
str.chars().map(ch -> ch - 'a').forEach(chars::add)
```

<sup>missing the type of `chars`, I just assumed it is `List<Integer>`</sup>